# netty - How to save the ChannelBuffer type to the file?

Tags: java, networking, network-programming, netty

I have tried to use this code:

```
saver=new FileOutputStream(file);
byte c;
while ( content.readable() ){ //content is a ChannelBuffer type
    c = content.readByte();
    saver.write(c); 
   }
```

but since the file stream is binary, the writing speed seems really slow! Is there any way to save the ChannelBuffer to the file really fast?

Comment: Try not writing a single byte a a time. The fact that the stream is "binary" has nothing to do with it; you need to read / write in larger chunks.

Comment: right. I expressed not clearly, What I mean by binary is that the data is a chunks, How could I write it to file in lager chunks? I mean, I want to save all bytes in the ChannelBuffer to file, but how?

Answer (score 8):

Try writing the whole buffer to file.  This example code is from netty file upload [app](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/codec-http/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/codec/http/multipart/AbstractDiskHttpData.java#L122).

```
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    FileChannel localfileChannel = outputStream.getChannel();
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = buffer.toByteBuffer();
    int written = 0;
    while (written < size) {
        written += localfileChannel.write(byteBuffer);
    }
    buffer.readerIndex(buffer.readerIndex() + written);
    localfileChannel.force(false);
    localfileChannel.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    ChannelBuffer cBuffer = ***;

    try (FileOutputStream foStream = new FileOutputStream(filepath)) {
        while (cBuffer.readable()) {
            byte[] bb = new byte[cBuffer.readableBytes()];
            cBuffer.readBytes(bb);
            foStream.write(bb);
        }
        foStream.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```